# Restricting access to localhost with firewalld

Tags: iptables, firewalld

I added direct rule to block localhost access to port 22 but it doesn't work. Basically chain OUTPUT looks like this:

```
Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 3160 packets, 271K bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 3701  385K LIBVIRT_OUT  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            
  543  114K ACCEPT     all  --  any    lo      anywhere             anywhere            
 3161  272K OUTPUT_direct  all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

As you see, the ACCEPT rule for loopback is above OUTPUT_direct chain, therefore whatever I put in this chain doesnt take effect for the loopback interface.

How can I make this firewalld blocking port 22 on loopback?